# Documentation about a jQuery function return

Tags: jquery

I've been looking at the API documentation for jQuery functions and one thing I cannot find is for any arbitrary function, what exactly does the function return. For example:

```
$(this).appendTo($someElement);
```

What does the appendTo function return. I looked at the documentation and it just says it returns a jQuery object, but it doesn't say what object in particular.

I wanna know because I want to be able to chain my statements without worrying about on what elements exactly I'm chaining on. Thanks

Comment: It returns the selected element(s), in this case jQuery wrapped `this` object.

Comment: In general, selectors return the selected; that's how come you can chain methods.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, jQuery functions will always receive the selected object. So in your case you'll get `$(this)` back.

There are exceptions of course:

- [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)
- [children](http://api.jquery.com/children/)
- [end](http://api.jquery.com/end/)
- ...

It should be fairly clear from the name of the function. If it seems to do something, rather than return something, it will return the same object you used the function on.